# How to loop a function and store multiple outputs in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

I have made the following function that has two (vector) outputs:

```
sample_vec <- function(v,n){
  currentsample <- sample(v,n) 
  m <- mean(currentsample) 
  s <- sd(currentsample)
  return(c(m,s))
}
```

How can I loop this 10000 times with argument:

```
sample_vec(gene_df$gene_length_bp,3)
```

while storing the two outputs in the two different columns of dataframe:

```
sdf <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 2))
colnames(sdf)[1] = "m"
colnames(sdf)[2] = "s"
```

(If you need data for argument: [downloaddata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sLJ34rnB6_RDTbUJSFhrdjeYrpxrR15n/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replicate`

```
n <- 1000
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
    replicate(n, sample_vec(gene_df$gene_length_bp,3),
    simplify = FALSE))
colnames(out) <- c("m", "s")
```

-output

```
> dim(out)
[1] 1000    2
> head(out)
         m         s
1 7822.333 3595.7399
2 2569.333  924.4806
3 2692.667 1296.6967
4 2913.333 2825.6844
5 5585.000  343.9608
6 2673.000 2360.7694
```

Comment: Always appreciate your base R approaches and for future (and current readers) if you could mention `?rbind.data.frame` is actually `?rbind` of the `data.frame` variant, though the term `rbind.data.frame` is never mentioned in rbind help.Unless I should be `?ing` elsewhere.

Comment: @Chris These are S3 methods.  If you check ?rbind, `For the default method, a matrix combining the ... arguments column-wise or row-wise.`  Also, check `methods('rbind')`.   `The method dispatching is not done via UseMethod(), but by C-internal dispatching. Therefore there is no need for, e.g., rbind.default.`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.frame()` in the last line of `sample_vec` instead of `return()` function. This would store `m` and `s` as data frame in the loop. Then you could use `lapply()` to iterate  `10000` times and finally using `bind_rows` from `tidyverse` to bind the outputs from all 10000 iterations.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

sample_vec <- function(v,n){
  currentsample <- sample(v,n) 
  m <- mean(currentsample) 
  s <- sd(currentsample)
  data.frame(m=m,s=s) # save m and s in df 
}


sdf <- bind_rows(
  lapply(1:10000, \(i)  sample_vec(gene_df$gene_length_bp,3))
)

head(sdf)
 
         m        s
1 4813.000 2925.076
2 6373.667 2238.629
3 7050.333 4395.800
4 5328.333 2529.838
5 4653.667 2697.535
6 4183.000 1165.786
```